# Import data with each value containing column lables

Tags: python, import

I have data in a text file with no headers. The values in each row have a label indicating which column they belong to. I want to take those labels as column names and feed the data under the columns.

I want to import the following from a text document (note the arrangement of values under columns is not constant):

```
Column1=variable11&Column2=variable12&Column3=variable13&Column4=variable14
Column2=variable22&Column1=variable12&Column3=variable23
Column1=variable13&Column3=variable33&Column2=variable32&Column4=variable34&Column5=variable35
```

I expect the result to be a table like this:

```
Column1         Column2         Column3         Column4         Column5
variable11      variable12      variable13      variable14  
variable21      variable22      variable23      
variable31      variable32      variable33      variable34      variable35
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas dataframes for it:

```
import pandas as pd

a='''Column1=variable11&Column2=variable12&Column3=variable13&column4=variable14
Column2=variable22&Column1=variable12&Column3=variable23
Column1=variable13&Column3=variable33&Column2=variable32&Column4=variable34&Column5=variable35'''

result = []

for line in a.split('\n'):
    dict_line = {}
    for chunk in line.split('&'):
        col, var = chunk.split('=')
        dict_line[col] = var
    result.append(dict_line)
pd.DataFrame(result)
```

will return you the dataframe:

```
    Column1     Column2     Column3     Column4     Column5     column4
0   variable11  variable12  variable13  NaN         NaN         variable14
1   variable12  variable22  variable23  NaN         NaN         NaN
2   variable13  variable32  variable33  variable34  variable35  NaN
```

Empty cells in this dataframe are filled with `NaN`

Comment: Is there a way to remove the repetition of the column names?

Comment: You have no repetitions in column names. Look, you have `column4=variable14` in the end of the first line. `column4` is not equal to `Column4`